# PDF converter for HTML

Tags: vb.net

I am searching for a product that converts HTML to PDF in VB. I have searched alot for the products, but most of them are very expensive or doesn't work very well. Can anyone suggest me of a good quality, working product?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use [htmldoc](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1)

Don't know if it fits your definition of "works very well", but for me, it does the trick.

A different approach is to install a print-to-pdf printer driver (such as freepdf), and print from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mPDF. mPDF is a PHP class which generates PDF files from UTF-8 encoded HTML. Its free and works very good.

http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Answer (score 0):

See [**WKHTMLPDF.**](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

I have checked quality and used this tool. This is the good one and Opensource. This is shell utility to convert html to pdf using the webkit rendering engine, and qt.